# Why is this $.getJSON call in the jquery documentation correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, option-type, optional-arguments

I am a little bit confused by the jQuery documentation. I am looking at [this page describing `$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). The code sample is:

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});
```

But the method signature is `jQuery.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] )`, where `data` is an object sent to the server, and `success` is a method called when the JSON request returns successfully.

So why does the example code work? It seems to have skipped the second argument. I would have expected the correct code to be:

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', {}, function(data) {
// and then the same from here
```

I know that the square brackets mean that the `[, data]` and `[, success]` arguments are optional, but I guess I don't understand how javascript deals with a variable number of arguments.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think it will check the parameter type, if it is `function` it will become `success`, otherwise it will become `data`, but I am not sure how jQuery do it

Comment: jquery functions use it's unique parsing method where it doesn't only check arguments but argument count and type as well.

Comment: Why not have a look at the source? [.getJSON()](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.3/jQuery.getJSON) (or [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) for the complete source)

Comment: Yeah, my guess is correct =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the jQuery source code :

```
// shift arguments if data argument was omitted
        if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
            type = type || callback;
            callback = data;
            data = undefined;
        }
```

So it works

Comment: Glad it was jQuery specific and not some magic law of javascript I hadn't met yet!

Answer (score 0):

Number of arguments:

```
arguments.length
```

Then they check for types of arguments and determine which arguments you have provided.

For example:

```
if(typeof arguments[0] === 'string') // first parameter is a string so it must be url
if(typeof arguments[1] === 'object') // second parameter is an object so it must be data passed to server
if(typeof arguments[2] === 'function') // third parameter is a function so it must be callback
```